# multi-field validation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a simple form with email & password. I want to show the submit button once BOTH the email & password are valid. My thoughts were when I run my handleValidator function I can check some sort of value of the "valid" property for email & "valid" property of pass. How do I access the valid property of an item?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"                     
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            >
<fx:Script>
    import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
    private function handleValidator ( eventObj:ValidationResultEvent ):void {

        if( eventObj.type==ValidationResultEvent.VALID
                          // what goes here?????
                          //  && emailValidator.valid = true ?????
                          //  && passValidator.valid = true  ??????

                          ){ 
            submit.visible = true;
        }
        else {
            submit.visible = false;
        }
    }


</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>

    <mx:EmailValidator id="emailValidator" source="{email}" property="text"
                       trigger="{email}" triggerEvent="change"
                       valid="handleValidator(event)" invalid="handleValidator(event)"
                       />
    <mx:StringValidator id="passValidator" source="{pass}" property="text"
                        trigger="{pass}" triggerEvent="change"
                        valid="handleValidator(event)" invalid="handleValidator(event)"
                        minLength="5" maxLength="10"
                        />
</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup>

<s:TextInput id="email" />
<s:TextInput id="pass" />
<s:Button id="submit" visible="false" />

</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with something like this. First put your validators into an array:

```
<mx:Array id="validators">
    <mx:EmailValidator id="emailValidator" source="{email}" property="text">

    <mx:StringValidator id="passValidator" source="{pass}" property="text"
        minLength="5" maxLength="10"/>
</mx:Array>
```

Add change event handler to both your inputs:

```
<s:TextInput id="email" change="validate()"/>
<s:TextInput id="pass" change="validate()"/>
```

Handler will trigger validation:

```
private function validate():void{
    //validate both your inputs simultaneously
    var errors:Array = Validator.validateAll(validators);
    if (errors.length>0){
        //hide submit button
    }else{
        //show submit button
    }
}
```

And that's all.

Comment: very nice & very streamlined. I'd give you extra points if I could

Comment: When adopting for Flex 4.x. you have to use <fx:Array> tag otherwise you'll get a "cannot resolve to a component" error. Also, it's not mentioned above but to use the Validator function you need to add: `import mx.validators.Validator;` Nice answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I would also go with 2DH for validation, also you can look into following two posts, which I often refer to when it comes to validation.

http://joelhooks.com/2009/02/01/form-validation-for-the-lazy-programmer-in-flex/

This explains the same technique given by 2DH

http:// aralbalkan.com/1125

this one adds a little more functionality for showing error tool tips in a better way.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

in handleValidator , check the event.currentTarget id to find out whether the email or the password has been validated. React accordingly, namely if the email or password is valid, increment a variable , if not valid , dispatch some form of error message to the user.

If both fields are valid, your variable should be equal to the number of fields being validated ( provided that the default value for the variable was 0 ) , you can then show your submit button.